# CFileDialog support XP and Vista

Tags: c++, windows-xp, windows-vista, cfiledialog

my app supports XP and up, and I'm trying to use the CFileDialog newer interfaces (i.e. GetIFileOpenDialog()) when running under Vista and up (to respect the limitations of those interfaces).

So I check for the OS version, and try to use those interfaces if appropriate, and fall back on older methods for XP. The problem is that running under XP I get LoadLibrary failures (the code is in a DLL), so there seems to be some early binding going on. As soon as I comment out the code that uses those interfaces then the LoadLibrary succeeds.

Is it possible at all to have CFileDialog code using Vista features running under XP, even if the code is not called?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually load the relevant library with `LoadLibrary()`, (it won't be loaded a second time, but you need a good handle for it) and then use `GetProcAddress()` to get the address of the function (`GetIFileOpenDialog`). If you just use the Vista function directly, it won't load on XP, since it does, as you say, bind the function directly.

Comment: Any idea how to find where GetIFileOpenDialog is implemented? I tried comdlg32.dll and it's not in there.

Comment: Hang on, this is using MFC, right? So, you will need to have the right version of MFC on the XP machine first of all.

Comment: Yes but I'm currently trying to dynamically call GetIFileOpenDialog() on a Windows 7 machine that I know works fine when I call it statically. The MFC dll jungle is a maze to sift through, and I can't find where GetIFileOpenDialog() is implemented. I even tried invoking everything through COM interfaces and I get the same problem (i.e. my dll won't load on XP). It's as if everything needs to be early binded.

Comment: Well, it seems like the class itself supports "non-vista": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386312.aspx
(See the comment under "Remarks")

Comment: No go, because of the early binding thing.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.